# How to view the column while using aggregate function

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have the below code which will aggregate customer state column and display highest mean of the payment_value column.
`data.groupby('customer_state').agg({'payment_value':'mean'}).max()`

Below is the output i get:

```
payment_value    258.00294
```

I want my output to be displayed along with the customer_state column name. Something as below where PB is the customer_state:

```
PB  258.002940
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because the parameter `customer_state` hasnt turn to a column, you need to reset index first and rename the column `payment_value` so it will be more easy to work with.

```
data.groupby(['customer_state']).agg({'payment_value': ['mean']}).reset_index()
data.columns = ['customer_state', 'payment_value']
data =  data.sort_values(['payment_value'], ascending = False)
```

Comment: i'm getting this error. ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 15 elements, new values have 2 elements

Comment: There was already a dataframe with the variable name as data. I just assigned a new variable and it worked fine